Two structs bind to a protocol with an optional variable error
I have two structs like this
struct LastKey:Equatable, MyProtocol {
  var id: UUID  
  let lowercase:String?

  var isValid:Bool {
    // calculate
  }
} 

struct FirstKey:Equatable, MyProtocol {
  var id: UUID
  let name:String?
}

protocol MyProtocol {
  var id:UUID { get set }
}

Then I decided to use this
func setLastKey(_ lastKey:MyProtocol) {
  let lastKey = LastKey()
  if lastKey.isValid { // do something }
}

But because lastKey is of type MyProtocol, and isValid is not on the protocol I have to add it as optional, because firstKey doesn't have this property.
If I change the protocol to
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
  var id:UUID { get set }
  @objc optional var isValid:Bool { get set }
}

then the structs whine with the following error:
Non-class type 'FirstKey' cannot conform to class protocol 'MyProtocol'
Non-class type 'LastKey' cannot conform to class protocol 'MyProtocol'


the answer below gives you a solution, but I want to point that func setLastKey(_ lastKey:MyProtocol) { let lastKey = LastKey()... is not dealing with lastKey:MyProtocol at all, it's always LastKey, since you are hiding protocol argument on the first line of your function. So maybe formulating a question more correctly would allow to see if there are any other options / issues here.

Instead of using optional and being forced to use @objc I would declare the protocol as
protocol MyProtocol {
  var id:UUID { get set }
  var isValid:Bool { get }
}

Note that I removed set for the isValid property because it goes better with how you declare it in LastKey and it doesn’t make much sense that you can set it externally.
And add a default implementation for those types that doesn’t need a custom logic
extension MyProtocol {
    var isValid: Bool { true }
}


It works. Thanks but this is something I don't understand. You extend the protocol by defining isValid as true. Can't it be simply included in the protocol itself instead of isValid { get }

No you can’t give a default value as part of the protocol declaration.

So, what isValid on the extension is doing?

It is a default implementation of the property but it's not actually part of the the protocol declaration (maybe definition is a better word).
